# Ограничения в таблице

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, организую мероприятие на 16 человек есть две абсолютно идентичные таблицы users и uchastniki, при нажатии на кнопку данные пользователя копирует из таблицы users в таблицу uchastniki, всё вроде бы хорошо, только никак не могу поставить ограничение, что бы после того как 16 человек подали заявку 17-тому выдавало что мест уже нет, вот попробовал написать код (сразу скажу что поставил значение $posts < 1 специально, просто тестил, с этим значением я добавил 5 пользователей) :
include_once("bd.php"); //подключение дб 
$query2 = ("SELECT * FROM uchastniki WHERE login='$login'");
$sql = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis2.php'>";
}
else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT login FROM uchastniki");
$posts = mysql_result($result); 
echo $posts; 
if($posts < 1){
$query = "INSERT INTO uchastniki SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id_user"; //регистрация пользователя 
mysql_query ( $query ); 
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=zapis1.php'>";
}else { echo "Нету свободных мест"; 
}}
mysql_close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте количество строк в базе участников. Если число меньше нужного, то добавляете строчку в базу. Ниже привел пример кода.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(`nomer`) FROM `uchastniki`");
$count = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if($count[0] < 16)
{
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO `uchastniki` ......');
}
else
{
    echo 'Вы не можете вступить';
}
```

Comment: сделал так, как вы сказали, добавил колонку nomer, $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`nomer`) FROM uchastniki"); - всё равно не ограничивает пользователей, добавляет всех подряд.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Привел пример кода. Если он вам не поможет, то я вам больше помочь не смогу.

Comment: разобрался, пришлось кое что подшаманить конечно, но вы меня навели на правильную мысль, лайк вам и принимаю ответ